# Mina - doDecode() can't return true when buffer is not consumed. (Hexdump: empty)

Tags: java, spring, sockets, apache-camel, mina

Im getting this error upon sending requests to a MINA endpoint

```
2017-10-17 00:26:44,156 [  NioProcessor-1] WrapperTagDecoder          DEBUG - Read message:{
      "Work" : "Eat",
      "Tag"    : "123"
    }, charset:utf-8
     2017-10-17 00:26:44,158 [- MinaThreadPool] Mina2Consumer              WARN  - Closing session as an exception was thrown from MINA
     2017-10-17 00:26:44,158 [- MinaThreadPool] DefaultIoFilterChain       WARN  - Unexpected exception from exceptionCaught handler.
     org.apache.camel.CamelException: org.apache.mina.filter.codec.ProtocolDecoderException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: doDecode() can't return true when buffer is not consumed. (Hexdump: empty)
```

Here is my MINA config:

Do I need to add something or I did something wrong?
Thanks!

```
<bean id="minaConfig1" class="org.apache.camel.component.mina2.Mina2Configuration">
    <property name="protocol" value="tcp" />
    <property name="encoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <property name="timeout" value="100" />
    <property name="host" value="${host}" />
    <property name="port" value="${port" />
    <property name="minaLogger" value="false" />
    <property name="codec" ref="wrapperTag1"></property>

    <property name="filters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="WhitelistFilter1" />
            <ref bean="SessionCountFilter1" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="WhitelistFilter1" class="org.abc.communication.logic.mina.WhitelistFilter">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="${allowedIP}"></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="1" value="${Whitelists}"></constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="SessionCountFilter1" class="org.abc.communication.logic.mina.SessionCountFilter" />

<bean id="wrapperTag1" class="org.abc.communication.logic.mina.WrapperTagProtocolCodecFactory">
    <constructor-arg value="utf-8" />
</bean>

<bean id="minaFactory" class="org.apache.camel.component.mina2.Mina2Component">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="camel"></constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="minaEndpointForPNS" factory-bean="minaFactory" factory-method="createEndpoint">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="minaConfig1"></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

I used Spring to input the config